# Train CK+ landmarks for expression-recognition with SVM

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, svm

I'm trying to develop a REAL TIME facial-expression recognition on mobile for my final thesis in university.

I have implemented in OpenCV and STASM library, a face detector using the first one and a landmark detector using the second one.

So, now i'm at this point:
[image: output after ASM]

Now, my idea was to use SVM for classification.
I have downloaded the CK+ dataset.
The thing that i can't understand is: how i can use the information of the Landmarks in the CK+'s dataset to do the training? 
I mean, initially, i thought to put all the X e Y coordinates of all the landmarks, corresponding to each frame, of each person, in a matrix.

So I would have had a labelled matrix containing N submatrices, where N was the number of people in my dataset.

I don't know if this would be the correct way to work.

However, I can't continue, because in the dataset not all people have the same number of frames for the different expressions, then having number of different frames, the sub-matrices can't merge together.

[image]

For example in this case, two people for the same expression had 18 or 11 frame.

Comment: do those images come with 'expression' labels ? i think, that's what you should use, not persons.

Comment: trim the dataset. Remove the extra frames from people who has the most number of expressions.

Comment: @blackibiza ok... and then, i have to use the X and Y coordinates of the landmarks for the SVM training or is better if i'll calculate the displacement between the (X,Y) in every frame?

Comment: @berak... yes, the images are labelled... but i can't understand how to do the training only with the information of the expression...

Comment: @luke88 you have to calculate the displacement again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, the coarse idea would go like this:

- for each image make a (flat, 1d) feature vector from your stasm points, x,y,x,y,x,y,x,y ...

  (you might have to normalize them, like get the boundingrect and subtract the position, divide by size)

  (taking the diff to the base model / neutral might be another idea to check)
- the training data set will be a Mat with 1 such feature per row, and the labels will have 1 expression id per row. (you want to make this *independant of the person*, because your later tests will work with *unseen* persons)
- for the prediction, treat your data in the very same way as for the training

---

```
Mat trainData, trainLabels;
// no idea about stasm, i'll just assume, you got a vector<float> of x,y points per image
for ( all images ) // not per person
{   
    trainData.push_back( Mat(points) );       // a single, flat float array
    trainLabels.push_back( expression_id );   // integer labels
}

trainData = trainData.reshape(1, numImages);  // numImg x numPoints*2 (x,y)

// for multi-class svm, kernelType = ml::SVM::POLY 
// and svmType = ml::SVM::NU_SVC with nu ~ 1/numExpressions maybe, 
// but parametering this is, where the *real* work starts ;(

svm->train(trainData, labels);

...

Mat test(points);

int expr_id = svm->predict(test);
```

Comment: for first, thanks for the answer... now like you said i'm in the "real" work.. indeed i'm having problem with the parameters of SVM... anyway, why you told that this idea is course?

Comment: another thing.. in the beginning my trainData matrix was a 158304x2 where 158304 was numImages x numFrames x numPoints, and i thought to reshape to numImages like you said. Now i have a matrix 582x544 where 582 is the numImages and 544 is the numPoints x numFrames x 2.. i have this error, and i can't understand if the problem are my trainData and trainLabels matrix: "OpenCV Error: Incorrect size of input array (Response array must be 1-dimensional) in cvPreprocessCategoricalResponses"..

Comment: the labels(responses) must be numImagesx1 (and int), 1 label per row

Comment: i know that i'm boring you, but now i have another error: "Bad argument (response #0 is not integral) in cvPreprocessCategoricalResponses" .. you know if there exists some example on how using SVM multiclass?

Comment: you're not boring, it's a long winded process (aka WORK). error says, your 1st label is not an integer. what about it ? (and no, if i'd knew a nice example, i'd pointed you to that earlier on.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66276/discussion-between-luke88-and-berak).